# ARIMA forecasts with R - how to update data

Tags: r

I've been trying to develop an ARIMA model to forecast wind speed values. I have a four year data series (from january 2008 until december 2011). The series presents 10 minute data, which means that in a day we have 144 observations. Well, I'm using the first three years (observations 1 to 157157) to generate the model and the last year to validate the model.
The thing is I want to update the forecast. On other words, when one forecast ends up, more data is added to the dataset and another forecast is performed. But the result seems like I had just lagged the original series. Here's the code:

```
#1 - Load data:
z=read.csv('D:/Faculdade/Mestrado/Dissertação/velocidade/tudo_10m.csv', header=T, dec=".")
vel=ts(z, start=c(2008,1), frequency=52000)

# 5 - ARIMA Forecasts:
library(forecast)
n=157157
while(n<=157200){
   amostra <- vel[1:n] # Only data until 2010
   pred <- auto.arima(amostra, seasonal=TRUE,
   ic="aicc", stepwise=FALSE, trace=TRUE,
   approximation=TRUE, xreg=NULL,
   test="adf",
   allowdrift=TRUE, lambda=NULL, parallel=TRUE, num.cores=4)

   velpred <- arima(pred) # Is this step really necessary?
   velpred


   predvel<- forecast(pred, h=12) # h means the forecast steps ahead
   predvel


   plot(amostra, xlim=c(157158, n), ylim=c(0,20), col="blue", main="Previsões e Observações", type="l", lty=1)
   lines(fitted(predvel), xlim=c(157158, n), ylim=c(0,20), col="red", lty=2)


n=n+12
}
```

But when it plot the results (I couldn't post the picture here), it exhibits the observed series and the forecasted plot, which seems just the same as the observed series, but one step lagged.

Can anyone help me examining my code and/or giving tips on how to get the best of my model? Thanks! (Hope my English is understandable...)

Comment: A small pic of the results is my own profile pic! :D

Comment: Try `plot(predvel)`, it should show your original series with the forecasted values, no need to overlay with `lines`

Comment: Thanks, mkemp6, but the problem when I do this is that the forecasted line turns into the observed line on every step of the model.